# How to edit iPhone Screencap without changing resolution

Tags: screen-casting, aspect, iphone

I need to do a basic cut from the middle of a screencast on an iPhone 11 Pro Max, but every method I've tried ends with the video being cropped to 16:9. How can I keep the original resolution?

Comment: what software are you using to edit?

Comment: Feels like something that should be native? the regular Photos App tools, iMovie (on iOS & Mac), & Premiere Rush

Comment: Include the software you're using, a screenshot of your export settings, etc.